# Conditional Statements to Check Length in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, match, row-number

This may be very simple, but I am just starting to learn. 
I want to use two conditional statement to the find the length of rows in a given dataset. So, for example I have a list of two people and their genders

```
P1 | P2 | Match | Same

M  | F  | FALSE | FALSE
M  | M  | TRUE  | TRUE
F  | M  | FALSE | FALSE
F  | F  | TRUE  | FALSE
```

I want to count the number of instances where `Match = TRUE` and `Same = FALSE`
for Men and for Women separately. I thought I might need to use a length function but it doesn't seem to be working for me...

Comment: `with (df1, sum(Match & !Same))#[1] 1`

Comment: When you say 'Men' and "Women' separately, which column do you choose i.e. P1 or P2 ?  `library(dplyr);df %>% group_by(P1) %>% summarise(Length = sum(Match & !Same))`

Comment: Ah thank you for your comment! but what it I want to count it between gender as well. so for example if I want only the sum if P1 = M

Comment: In that case extract the 'M' from 'P1' i.e. `with(subset(df1, P1 == 'M'),sum(Match & !Same)))`

Answer (score 0):

I'd first make an extra variable (`Match & !Same`) and then make a `table` of gender by that extra variable:

```
df1$Combo <- with(df1, Match & !Same)
with(df1, table(P1, Combo))
# or maybe you want the following ...
with(df1, table(P1, P2, Combo))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it in this way:

```
sum(dt$Match == TRUE & dt$Same == FALSE)
```

I think since it is not numeric using the sum function acted as a 'length' function for me.